# systemd: Unknown key name 'ConditionEnvironment' in section 'Unit'

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I'm using systemd version 246:

```
$ systemctl --version                           
systemd 246 (246.2-1-arch)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

which documents `ConditionEnvironment` in its systemd.unit manpage. However, if I use it in my unit file `~/.config/systemd/user/i3-session-pre.target` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=i3 session
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
BindsTo=graphical-session-pre.target
ConditionEnvironment=XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=i3
```

I get the following entry in my user journal:

```
systemd[599]: /home/****/.config/systemd/user/i3-session-pre.target:5: Unknown key name 'ConditionEnvironment' in section 'Unit', ignoring.
```

Also `systemd-analyze condition` fails to handle this condition:

```
$ systemd-analyze condition ConditionEnvironment=XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=i3
Cannot parse "ConditionEnvironment=XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=i3".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strange, I'm on systemctl 246-2 (debian testing), also using i3.  I find that when I add the target you wrote verbatim, the target is reached without error.  If I change the condition to something which is wrong (`XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome`), the target is still reached.

Comment: When I run `systemd-analyze` using the example from the manpage, things seem to work.  It's something specific to `ConditionEnvironment`

Comment: I wonder if this feature isn't finished yet. It was only just released with rev 246 about 2.5 weeks ago.  [The PR](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15817) was only merged in May, so it's possible that it's not finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong.  I think there's a bug in systemd.

On Debian testing (systemd 246, and later on 246.1 after upgrading) I observed the following:

`ConditionEnvironment=` was only [released with version 246](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/systemd/systemd/master/NEWS) on July 30 2020 (2.5 weeks before time of writing) and [the pull request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15817) was merged on May 15.  Therefore, it's reasonable to assume it isn't mature yet.

Here's a test that leads me to think it's a bug:

```
$ systemd-analyze condition \
    'ConditionKernelVersion='  \
    'ConditionKernelVersion='  \
    'ConditionACPower=' \
    'ConditionArchitecture=' \
    'AssertPathExists=' \
    'ConditionEnvironment='
Cannot parse "ConditionEnvironment=".
```

If I run each condition one-by-one, they all parse the empty expression except for `ConditionEnvironment=`.

I tried your target verbatim (also from an i3 environment) and I found that `ConditionEnvironment=` had no influence on whether I could reach the target.  I tried corrent and incorrect values. Therefore this problem is not specific to `systemd-analyze`.

One thing I did find super-interesting is a comment in [xdg-autostart-generator/xdg-autostart-condition.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/systemd/systemd/master/src/xdg-autostart-generator/xdg-autostart-condition.c):

```
 * This binary is intended to be run as an ExecCondition= in units generated
 * by the xdg-autostart-generator. It does the appropriate checks against
 * XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP that are too advanced for simple ConditionEnvironment=
 * matches.
```

I think the bug is valid, but I find it interesting that a generator was made (and deployed as `/lib/systemd/systemd-xdg-autostart-condition`) to overcome a problem experienced with the exact environment you are looking into.

I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=968612) with Debian.  I expect the debian devs will take a look and forward upstream to the systemd devs.

Comment: Thanks for the further analysis and for filing the bug report. As it seems to be an upstream bug I mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Debian devs advised me to forward the bug [upstream](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16781)

Comment: [A commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/625a164069aff9efb61dcc5916c572f53c2a7ab0) was just made today to systemd which should address this issue.  It was made on the `master` branch, so you should see it in systemd 247

Comment: Thanks :) looking forward to the fix in v247.