# systemd unit conditional execution based on network I'm connected to (VPN issue)

Tags: networking, systemd

From the [systemd.unit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), I know about conditions such as ConditionPathExists=, ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=, etc. However, what I seem to need is a condition that is dependent upon a specific default gateway address.

Specifically, I want to start the `nordvpnd.service` (and socket) only when I am not connected to the office network. My NordVPN service is set to `autostart` with `killswitch enabled`, which is the way I want it to be everywhere except at the office.

When at the office, I will always have a specific default gateway IP address. It seems I could use this fact to implement a condition in the `nordvpnd.service` unit file. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

```
[Unit]
Description=NordVPN Daemon
Requires=nordvpnd.socket
After=network-online.target
Condition=??????

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nordvpnd
NonBlocking=true
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest something, pls check if this can be useful:

What you can do is fetch the default gateway and set the environment variable and then use the ConditionEnvironment  for that.

Below are the commands that can fetch the gateway ip and set the environment variable:

```
gw=$(ip r | grep default | grep -oE "([[:digit:]]+\.)+{3}[[:digit:]]")

if [ "$gw" == "192.168.X.X" ]; then export officeNetwork=1; else export officeNetwork=0; fi
```

Here replace 192.168.X.X with your office's default gateway IP

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I like your idea. However, the complete solution requires a unit file (or similar) to run this script and a few more details. (Also, ideally it should work when `ip r` returns multiple gateways, such as in a device with two network interfaces.)

Comment: Have you run into the bug mentioned here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/605102/15010 I am encountering that issue on an up-to-date Arch Linux now

Comment: no.. but if thats giving you a problem then another way could be creating a tmp file instead of setting environment variable if its office network and then use ConditionPathExists